# How to install Anaconda in virtual environment of conda.

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda3 and for using python2 with Jupyter-notebook I made a virtual environment py27 and made ipython kernel in that environment now I see an option to choose python2 or python2 kernel in Ipython notebook.
Now when I use python2 kernel it has no packages in it( obviously I didnt installed any in environment py27 ).
My question is how can I install anaconda2 in the virtual environment py27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activating the environment with

on Linux/MacOS:

```
source activate py27
```

or on Windows:

```
activate py27
```

just type:

```
conda install anaconda
```